# Need to create a monit cfg for network interface

Tags: linux, performance, alert, monit, network-interface

I need to create a monit configuration file for network interface lo.

The format for a network interface is:

```
CHECK NETWORK <unique name> <ADDRESS <ipaddress> | INTERFACE <name>>
```

I am making the command as

```
Check network lo
```

It says "lo not found"

Another question I had was how to reduce the number of alerts. I get an alert every 2 mins for a particular service. 
By using

```
set daemon n (n being the number of seconds here)
```

Does make all the alerts restricted to the number of seconds defined here. 
I wanted a particular service alert to be recieved after a certain time period. So I put a line set daemon 600 (to receive alert after 10 mins) in the monit.cfg of this service. But I'm now getting all the alerts after 10 mins only.

Could someone please cast some light on the same.

Answer (score 0):

For first point, what the goal of monitoring localhost interface. I can't find any relevant use case for this.

For second point, your are misusing the "set daemon" property.
This property is the interval for monit to "wake-up" and perform checks if needed.

You should use configuration in rules instead either to check differently like:

```
if does not exist 3 times in 5 cycles then alert
```

You could also set reminder as monit is only sending alert when the alert is triggered (upper will be after the the 3 third fail)

```
 SET ALERT mail-address [WITH] REMINDER [ON] number [CYCLES]
```

Reminder monit documentation is here : https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html